# Java Regex Program Not Working for All Inputs

Tags: java, regex, input

This is my current program. It is working fine for the given string INPUT.
But not working for other inputs. I want it to work for others too like if i < 30 then it should detect literals, keywords, and variables from it too.

Please guide me with the mistake and help me to correct it. 
Thank you in advance.

This is the complete class.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Test {

    static String[] keyword = {"abstract", "assert", "boolean", "break", "byte", "case", "catch", "char", "class", "continue",
        "default", "do", "double", "else", "enum", "extends", "final", "finally", "float", "for", "if",
        "implements", "import", "instanceof", "int", "interface", "long", "native", "new", "package", "private",
        "protected", "public", "return", "short", "static", "string", "strictfp", "super", "switch", "this",
        "throw", "throws", "transient", "try", "void", "volatile", "while"};

    static boolean labelsrun = false;
    private static String REGEX = "((?=[a-z_0-9]|[a-z])[a-z_0-9]+(?=\\s*=))";
    private static String INPUT = "public static void main(String[]args)\n" + "{\n" + "    String a=\"Malik\";\n"
            + "    int i=1;\n" + "    double j=2;\n" + "}";

    static JLabel identifiers = new JLabel(""), literals = new JLabel(""), keywords = new JLabel("");

    public static void check_Identifiers(String a[]) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 2; i < a.length; i++) {
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile(REGEX, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
            Matcher m = p.matcher(a[i]);

            if (m.find()) {
                if (count == 0) {
                    identifiers.setText(identifiers.getText() + " " + m.group());
                    count++;
                } else if (count > 0) {
                    identifiers.setText(identifiers.getText() + ", " + m.group());
                }

            }
        }
        count = 0;
    }

    public static void check_Literals(String a[]) {
        int count = 0;
        String regex = "=.*";
        String b = "";

        for (int i = 2; i < a.length; i++) {
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
            Matcher m = p.matcher(a[i]);

            if (m.find()) {
                if (m.group().contains("=")) {
                    b = m.group();
                    b = b.replaceAll("=", "");
                    b = b.replace(";", "");
                }
                if (count == 0) {
                    literals.setText(literals.getText() + " " + b);
                    count++;
                } else if (count > 0) {
                    literals.setText(literals.getText() + ", " + b);
                }
            }
        }
        count = 0;
    }

    public static void check_Keywords(String a[]) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < keyword.length; j++) {
                String regex = ".*\\b" + keyword[j] + "\\b.*";
                if (a[i].matches(regex)) {
                    if (count == 0) {
                        keywords.setText(keywords.getText() + " " + keyword[j]);
                        count++;
                    } else if (count > 0) {
                        keywords.setText(keywords.getText() + ", " + keyword[j]);
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        count = 0;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a[] = INPUT.toLowerCase().split("\n");
        check_Identifiers(a);
        check_Literals(a);
        check_Keywords(a);
    }
}
```

This is the method having problem. Currently, it is working only if the input is having = operator. But, how do it make it work for all operators? or at least > < along with =

```
public void check_Literals(String a[]) {
    int count = 0;
    String regex = "=.*";
    String b = "";

    for (int i = 2; i < a.length; i++) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(a[i]);

        if (m.find()) {
            if (m.group().contains("=")) {
                b = m.group();
                b = b.replaceAll("=", "");
                b = b.replace(";", "");
            }
            if (count == 0) {

                literals.setText(literals.getText() + " " + b);
                count++;
            } else if (count > 0) {
                literals.setText(literals.getText() + ", " + b);
            }
        }
    }
    count = 0;
}
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Try to create a [mcve]: (a) define the input, expected output, actual output (b) only show the code that's relevant to your question (i.e. no need to post all the GUI stuff)

Comment: Updated Question.

Comment: Wherever you write "working" in your question, replace it with *the actual behaviour* you expect to see.  (E.g., use "returns true" and "returns false" instead of "works" and "doesn't work".)

Comment: Can you please add some test cases to it. Like pattern you want to validate

Comment: Do we really need to use `swing` for a `regex` problem ? I don't believe this is minimal... I see a lot fo code but no input/output expected. Still not a [mcve] that could be answered...

Comment: Other patterns are `if i<3` or `if (i < 5)` or `if i > ANOTHER_VALUE;`